# Validate email address on exchange server

Tags: vb.net, smtp, exchange-server, email-validation

I'm allowing users to manage a distribution list stored in a database. Users are only allowed to enter emails that are @mydomain.com. A web based application then takes the distribution list and sends emails. I'd like to validate that the email is valid before sending an email from the application.

To send an email I'm using this code:

```
    Dim SendTo As String = "ThisIsNotARealEmailAddress@mydomain.com"
    Dim SentFrom As String = "me@mydomain.com"
    Dim MessageBody As String = "blah blah blah"
    Dim MessageSubject As String = "This is the subject"


    Dim mm As New MailMessage(SentFrom, SendTo)
    mm.Subject = MessageSubject
    mm.IsBodyHtml = False
    mm.Priority = MailPriority.High
    mm.Body = MessageBody

    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
    smtp.Send(mm)
```

If the SendTo is not a valid email address the server returns this error:

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.1.1 <ThisIsNotARealEmailAddress@mydomain.com>... User unknown
```

Is there anyway to validate the email when the email address is added to the database, instead of a `try catch` block when sending the email?

Comment: You can do a query against the AD domain when the email addresses are added. There should be plenty of examples out there. But you will still have errors when email addresses are changed or destroyed unless your admins update your database too.

Comment: @Bill ~ I didn't consider when email addresses change or get deleted. I'll just do my due diligence to get a valid email from AD upon submission, and then catch errors when sending. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The users are only sending to your domain? And you control the domain? And its a windows domain? Just query the AD and get their email address from the AD without asking them. Would that be valid? I presume this is a windows application, not a web app.

Comment: I've considered validating the email against Active Directory.  I'm not a mail sever guy, so let me ask this: If I validate against AD, will there ever be a case that a mailbox exists on the mail server but does not have an AD record?

Comment: @zeroef ~ there are plenty of mailboxes on the Exchange that don't exist in AD, but here's the catch. They can't get to the domain if they're not in AD, so they can't login to Exchange. Additionally, by my method, you don't ask them for an email address, you just magic it up out of LDAP. If none exists on the AD account, THEN you prompt for an email address.

Comment: @drachenstern - I see our disconnect. I've got no trouble pulling the email address from the currently logged in user. What I have is one user, entering multiple email addresses of other users.

Comment: @zeroef ~ oh, well in that case, just validate what's keyed in against AD. Yes, you can assume that the active email address will be there. Alternately, just send them an email and watch for bouncebacks, that's the only other proven way.

Comment: @drachenstern - Sending a confirmation message when added to the distribution list could kill two birds with one stone. It could validate the email is valid as well as give the user an option to "unsubscribe" from the distro.

Comment: @zeroef hence the reason it's preferred.